# How to save 12-digit bank account numbers with leading or trailing zeros in SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to save 12-digit customer account numbers in a database with 0's, which are prepended or appended to the base account number, e.g. this is what I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM customer;

 id | Name| AccNumber
----+-----+-----
  2 |   A | 000123456789
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM customer;

 id | Name| AccNumber
----+-----+-----
  2 |   A | 123456789000
```

But when I'm trying to save the account number (`000123456789` or `123456789000`) in the `customer` table, it saves the number like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer;

 id | Name| AccNumber
----+-----+-----
  2 |   A | 123456789
```

I have tried with datatype as `int`, `varchar`, `nvarchar` of `AccNumber` column.

Comment: If you save as varchar, it should not be discarding leading zeroes.  Perhaps your app layer is using an input stripped of leading zeroes?  Also, do you ever plan to do math on this account number?

Comment: have you tried to save it as varchar/string/text?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : thanks for your time and reply. :)
got  my answer.

Comment: @anakpanti :- thanks for your time and reply. :) got my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `VARCHAR` datatype and insert data like this

```
insert into customer (AccNumber) values ('000123456789') -- single quotes
```

not like this

```
insert into customer (AccNumber) values (000123456789)
```

When you are not using single quotes on numbers with leading zero's then it will be parsed as integers so the leading zero's will be removed before inserting into `varchar` column

`Numeric` datatypes remove leading zeros while storing because it is of no use

Comment: If he is doing the insert from something like Java, the answer could be more complicated than this.  +1 though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Ohh.. Am just a `SQL` guy with no idea about Java ;)

Comment: @Prdp :- thanks.., as i am fresher and don't have much knowledge about db, It works fine for me. :)
while inserting value i was forget to add 'single quotes' to the value.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to lose leading zeroes make sure that you have the following:

- **SQL datatype**: `VARCHAR`
- **.NET datatype**: if you use Entity Framework, the property should be of type `String`. If you are using ADO.NET, make sure that account parameter is o type `String` (or `System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar`, depending on how you write the parameterized query)

Comment: Alexei :- yes I'll look in to it.thanks for your reply.. :)